# Why doesn't this mod rewrite trigger? (update: relative and absolute rewrite pathing)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^contact/([a-zA-Z]*)/([0-9]*)/?$ /contact/new.php?unit_id=$2&unit_type=$1 [NC,L]
```

I have checked this against two online htaccess validators ([one here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=47ddaacf-b131-58a3-9ba7-ff57fbb3902b)) and can't see why it doesn't trigger.

Attempted URL:

> https://morris.website.co.uk/contact/ee/1302

This goes to the 404 page not found link.

But manually setting the URL to

> https://morris.website.co.uk/contact/new.php?unit_id=1302&unit_type=ee

Works correctly.

The `.htaccess` is in a subfolder (`/contact`)

The root folder `.htaccess` does not have any other relevant mod rewrites but it does set the error pages and a few other global settings:

```
ErrorDocument 400     /index.php
ErrorDocument 401     /index.php
ErrorDocument 403     /index.php
ErrorDocument 404     /index.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;" "expr=%{HTTPS} == 'on'"

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^$
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/
RewriteRule  .*              -    [R=403,L]
```

- I have tried placing the rewrite lines in the root .htaccess but this didn't change anything.

I'm sure this is silly, but I just can't see why the `/contact/.htaccess` is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing the question; I discovered that putting the code in the **root path** `.htaccess` and then *deleting the folder specific `.htaccess`* (a crucial part I'd missed before) seemed to resolve the problem.

It looks like folder specific `.htaccess` does not like absolute pathing rewrites.

Comment: This is not surprising at all. It actually is documented behavior which does make a lot of sense. Dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") operate on a _relative_ path base. That is why the pattern you use in the `RewriteRule` has to match the _relative_ path, so without leading slash. Opposed to that is the _real_ http server's host configuration. `RewriteRule`s implemented in there operate on _absolut_ paths. That location should be preferred for rule implementations for a number of reasons. I suggest you start reading a bit through the documentation of the tool you use...